# cuts in the dataset with python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy

Im studying the sun frequencies during one month every minute. So I have one matrix M with 43200 elements, one per minute.

The way to do the power spectrum for all the elements is:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
from scipy import fftpack

M=np.loadtxt('GOLF-SOHO-Sol.dat')
N=len(M)
dt=1

t= np.arange(0., N, dt)
yt = M


frecs= fftpack.fftfreq(yt.size, dt)        
fft_yt = fftpack.fft(yt)                   
vector_amp = np.abs(fft_yt)                 

pl.subplot(212)
pl.xlim(-0.5, 0.5)
pl.plot(frecs, vector_amp, color="blue", linestyle="-", linewidth=1.5)
pl.xlabel('Frecuencia (Hz)')
pl.ylabel('Espec. amplitud')
pl.title('Espectro de amplitud')
marcasx = np.arange(-0.5, 0.5, 0.1)                    # vector de marcas en x
pl.xticks(marcasx)

pl.show()
```

The problem is that now I want to make some cuts in this matrix. I only need the datas every 12 hours (when it is sunny). So in my matrix M I need for example that the first 720 are the same but the nexts 720 have to be 0, the nexts 720 the originals and the nexts 720 zero, etc.

How can I compute this? I should do a bucle with while in which every 720 dates it changes.

Thank you in advance. I hope I was clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# your data values (all ones for illustration)
>>> values = numpy.ones( (43200,) )

# reshape to matrix with rows of 720 samples
>>> mat    = values.reshape( (60, 720) )

# now it's easy to set alternating rows to 0.0
>>> mat[1::2, :] = 0

# and because y is a view of your data, "values" now
# has zeroes in the right places
>>> values[710:730]
array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
```

Comment: but I need that the first 720 numbers are what it is matrix M (not value 1), the following 720 numbers zero, the following 720 the value of M, the following zero, etc. all the time alternating until get the 43200 numbers. Maybe is what you said but I think I didn't understand it. I will try now to see how it works. Thanks for your time!

Comment: That is exactly what this does. The "1"'s are only there because I needed a `numpy.array` of length 43200. You have the luxury of already having that! Change `values` by your variable `M` (apart from `values = numpy.ones(...)` ofc.) and you should be good to go.

Comment: Yeah It's true! Im sorry. It works!! I just needed to reshape ir again and perfect :) Thank you so much.